# How can I create a bindable command proxy

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am currently developing a Windows store app using the MVVM pattern. The ViewModel implements a couple of commands that are used by the view. In some cases I want the view to trigger more than just one command. Therefore I created a CommandGroup class that is derived from ICommand and holds an observable collection of commands. In order to be able to populate this collection using XAML I created another class called CommandProxy that is derived from DependencObject and also implements ICommand.

The idea is to support something like this within the view:

```
<Button Content="Test">
   <Button.Command>
      <vm:CommandGroup>
         <vm:CommandGroup.Commands>
            <vm:CommandProxy Command="{Binding Command1}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Object1}"/>
            <vm:CommandProxy Command="{Binding Command2}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Object2}"/>
            <vm:CommandProxy Command="{Binding Command3}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Object3}"/>
         </vm:CommandGroup.Commands>
      </vm:CommandGroup>
   </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

Everything looks fine when doing a syntax check, but the bindings are not resolved at runtime. This can be reproduced using the following example assuming the ViewModel implements the command MyCommand and the view contains an element called MyElement:

```
<Button Content="Test">
   <Button.Command>
      <vm:CommandProxy Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyElement}"/>
   </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

This is a simplyfied version of the CommandProxy class that can be used to reproduce the issue:

```
public class CommandProxy : DependencyObject, ICommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(object), typeof(CommandProxy), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CommandProxy), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Command
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Command Parameter
    /// </summary>
    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event used to singnal that CanExecute has changed
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create new CommandGroupElement
    /// </summary>
    public CommandProxy()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine whether command can be executed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Command != null)
            return Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter);
         return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute Command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">Parameter</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Command != null)
            Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise CanExecuteChanged event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void raiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        raiseCanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise CanExecuteChanged event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Parameter</param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void raiseCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
           CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Is there anybody who can tell me what I'm doing wrong or explain me why this does not work?

Kind regards

Thomas

Comment: By not resolved at run-time you mean there are databinding errors in your output? Please post the error

Comment: CAn you give a use case scenario for your CommandProxy?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just bind to a command that calls the others?

Comment: There are no binding errors. The DependencyProperties always contain the default value specified in the property metadata (in this example it is null, but if you specify another default value the DependencyProperties contain this value). It looks like databinding isn't processed at all.

Comment: The idea behind this is separating the view ans the viewnodel in a way that the viewmodel does not need to know anything about the view. In certain cases a button for example may have to save data and close a popup or trigger navigation. Of course this can be solved using view specific commands or codebehind, but to really seperate view and coding I want my viewmodelbase to expose a set of service commands that can be uses by the view for manipulating elements and navigation and that can be accessed by XAML and databinding. So there should be no need for view spec. commands in the viewmodel.

Comment: How are you associating your ViewModel and View and what is your VM's definition? When are they getting assigned? Do you need to raise property changed? Have you tried creating a IValueConverter on your Binding that only calls Debugger.Break (to debug the binding). Have you tried go to tools->options and Output I think and turn Bindings verbosity up higher to see possible warnings?

Comment: The ViewModel binding is created using XAML:

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MyViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>

The output is set to the option that should display all binding messages, but it does not display any message.
So far I haven't tried using a ValueConverter for debugging or raising PropertyChanged for the DataContext itself.
I am going to try that asap and let you know the results.

Comment: Tonight I tried to use an IValueConverter that calls the debugger. Unfortunately no luck. The value converter is not being called at all. Any other ideas how I could do some further investigations?

Comment: I have't solve the problem yet, but it seems I am getting closer... First of all the CommanProxy class needs to be derived from FrameworkElement in order to have a DataContext property. When I set this property in the coding, binding to the ViewModel works. However binding to other FrameworkElements still does not work. I noticed that CommandProxy's parent element is always null, so I assume that the instance is not included in the logical tree. This would explain why the DataContext is null by default and why binding to other FrameworkElements does not work. Any ideas?